# How to "reset" an overridden Prototype method back to its original behaviour

Tags: javascript, date, prototype, jira

A script that I cannot control or remove has decided to override the default behaviour of the `Date.prototype.setFullYear` method. This causes problems for several libraries - such as `date-fns` - that our code relies heavily on.

Is there any way to "reset" the `Date.prototype.setFullYear` function back to its original behaviour? It does not matter whether the script that modified the prototype originally works afterwards or not - I don't need it to work, I just cannot remove it easily.

**Update:**

*The script that causes problems is one of many bundled on the Jira Core 7.13.3 platform that loads on all pages. It is named `calendar-lib`, and causes issues when developing plugins on the platform.*

*Because `calendar-lib` is a part of the base Jira installation, we cannot control the loading order; the offending script will always load first - as far as I know.*

*Like @Jonas suggested it turns out that the native method is stored in a variable named `Date.prototype.__msh_oldSetFullYear` which perhaps could be used reset the global behaviour with @Haseeb's answer.*

**Update 17.06.19:**

This issue has now been confirmed by the Jira developer team:
https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-69491

**Solution:**

As pointed out by @Jonas and @Rob in the comments, setting the following statement on the starting point of our application solved the issue:

`Date.prototype.setFullYear = Date.prototype.__msh_oldSetFullYear;`

Where `Date.prototype.__msh_oldSetFullYear` is the native implementation (luckily) stored and exposed by the offending `calendar-lib` code.

There were many really good suggestions in the comments below, so be sure to check those out if you are in a similar situation.

Thanks!

Comment: No, if its lost once, it can't be reforged. The part that overrides it has to keep a reference to the original method, maybe it also exposes it?

Comment: Can you run your own scripts before the problematic script is loaded?

Comment: You can bring back builtin methods from another realm (typically an iframe), but really you should prevent that script from messing with them in the first place. Place a bug report against Jira if they're destroying builtins.

Comment: Do you have control over when the offending script is loaded/imported?  Some context regarding that inclusion could provoke some ideas.

Comment: Thanks for many really good suggestions! I have added some more context to the question, and will give all answers a spin.

Comment: If your last statement is correct, you can simply do `Date.prototype.setFullYear = Date.prototype.__msh_oldSetFullYear`. That may have side effects on whatever is using *calendar-lib*.

Comment: @RobG, I will give your exact solution a try. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Jonas and @Rob in the comments of the original question, setting the following statement on the starting point of our application solved the issue:

```
Date.prototype.setFullYear = Date.prototype.__msh_oldSetFullYear;
```

Where `Date.prototype.__msh_oldSetFullYear` is the native implementation of `setFullYear` that (luckily) had stored and exposed through a variable by the offending `calendar-lib` code.

There were other really good suggestions in the comments below the original post as well - such as creating an iFrame and extracting it from there - so be sure to check those out if you are in a similar situation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do

**Option 1** - This will override the function globally.

```
let obj = new Date();
obj.__proto__.setFullYear = function(){
   //your override code goes in here.
}
```

**Option 2** - This will override the method only to your local scope or limited to the scope of your object instantiated.

```
  let obj = new Date();
  obj.setFullYear = function(){
    //your override code goes in here
  }
```

Hopefully this should work for you.

Comment: See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) regarding the use of `__proto__`, it is strongly recommended against. There are (recent) standards compliant ways to access an object's `[[Prototype]]`.

Comment: While not a solution one ever want to use, this might be needed to reset the functions behaviour. The only downside though is that one manually have to replicate the original functionality. Thanks for the tip, I will give it a try in combination with the comments above.

Comment: @TormodHaugene—if you intend to "reset" the method, you can use *Date.prototype* instead of using the non–standard `__proto__` property of a Date instance. Note that this may have side effects on whatever is using *calendar-lib*.